# How do I set pool_timeout to infinity in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

I'm building an API for a client, that receives multiple requests at the same time. Each request needs access to a PostgreSQL database, and so I use connection pooling to handle the concurrent requests.

Now, it so happens that sometimes the client sends no requests for more than a week or so. In case of such an event, I don't want the connections to ever close because of a timeout (due to an idle connection).

I'm using the SQLAlchemy API to handle the database connections and pooling, and I see a `pool_timeout` parameter in the `sqlalchemy.create_engine` method, which is quoted verbatim, "the number of seconds to wait before giving up on getting a connection from the pool."

Is there a way to have a timeout of infinity (i.e disabling timeout) by setting a value (like -1) to this parameter? I couldn't find anything on this in the documentation.

Comment: Dear @Train Heartnet, could you be so kind as to provide some reproducible code? 

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

I dug into this a little bit today and discovered that under the hood, that timeout ends up getting passed to Queue object (https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py#L97, https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py#L117), which will block forever if timeout is set to None:

> If optional args `block` is True and `timeout` is None (the
>           default), block if necessary until an item is available. If
>           `timeout` is a positive number, it blocks at most `timeout`
>           seconds and raises the `Empty` exception if no item was
>           available within that time.  Otherwise (`block` is false),
>           return an item if one is immediately available, else raise the
>           `Empty` exception (`timeout` is ignored in that case).

(from https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/c785a528ea200a8905d1b5d7ab4088d501606d2b/lib/sqlalchemy/util/queue.py#L135)